# Data structures lower bounds on Turing machines

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.data-structures, lower-bounds, turing-machines

Have there been any results on lower bounds for implementing data structures on Turing machines, e.g. stacks, queues, etc ?

I guess that people are mostly interested in models with random access, but I still wonder.

Comment: You mean lower-bounds directly for TMs? I mean it is usually possible to translate the lower-bounds for RAM to lower-bounds for TM, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking directly for TM.